# How to read the result (XML) from webservice C#

Tags: c#, xml

I have problem when I try get attributes the xml, likes ID, Name, Age.

```
<Table xmlns="http://localhost:8099/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <ID>1</ID>
   <Name>John</Name>
   <Age>25</Age>
</Table>
```

```
XmlDocument xmldoc = new XmlDocument();
xmldoc.Load(rd); 
var employee= doc.Descendants("Table ").Select(x => new
          {
              ID= x.Element("ID"),
              Name= x.Element("Name"),
              Age= x.Element("Age"),
          }).FirstOrDefault();

Response.Write(employee.Name);
```

any body can improve my code?

Comment: Please could you add details of the issue that you are facing. I.E. what is the problem you have declaring the node?

Comment: @JamesWilson i want get attribute Name, Age from the xml.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using `XmlDocument` or `XDocument`? I think it is `XDocument` because `XmlDocument` doesn't contain the `Descendants` method. Try this:

**EDIT (adding namespace):**

```
  XDocument xmldoc = XDocument.Load("myxml.xml");
        var @namespace = xmldoc.Root.GetDefaultNamespace();// Or var @namespace = "http://localhost:8099/"
        var employee = xmldoc.Descendants(@namespace + "Table").Select(x => new
        {
            ID = x.Element(@namespace + "ID"),
            Name = x.Element(@namespace + "Name"),
            Age = x.Element(@namespace + "Age"),
        }).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: the result "Object reference not set to an instance of an object.".

Comment: @Roberts, Is your xml file correct? For me it is working without xmlns="http://localhost:8099/"

Comment: The original xml has a namespace. You don't account for it, so your code will break.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, Thanks for reporting, I fixed code

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var xml = @"<Table>
              <ID>1</ID>
              <Name>John</Name>
              <Age>25</Age>
           </Table>"; // replace this by webservice response 
        XDocument xmldoc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
        var employee = xmldoc.Descendants("Table").Select(x => new
        {
            ID = x.Element("ID").Value,
            Name = x.Element("Name").Value,
            Age = x.Element("Age").Value,
        }).FirstOrDefault();
        Console.WriteLine(employee.Name);
```

Comment: The original xml has a namespace. You don't account for it, so your code will break.